# How we can do ajax login in ASP.NET with ACS

Tags: c#, acs

I am using azure Access Control Service (ACS) in my web application to authenticate users from different identity providers. I successfully registered my application to use ACS. Previously I was using ASP.NET Membership database to authenticate user and there are some pages in my application where user can do ajax-logIn (In which case no page refresh / reload happen and user gets logged in).

How can I do this using ACS login system?

Comment: Please don't use code-markup as highlighting. That's not what it's for. =)